# Maximum Memory Usage of CloudML Online Prediction Instances

Tags: google-cloud-ml

What is the maximum peak memory usage for serving tf models?

For example, to process some high-res images using a deep convolution net, we might require 40GB+ in memory usage.

Currently, CloudML charges per NodeHour. Specifically, how is memory applied?